# Splitting a claim into several small claims

Tags: england-and-wales, small-claims-court

UK, small claims court question.

Is it permissible to split a large claim into several small claims, against multiple defendants, arguing a different cause of action in each?

Consider this hypothetical and entirely fictional case:

**Adam** inherits a valuable piece of art (e.g. a painting).  **Adam** has no interest in art, and decides to sell.

**Bill** contracts to handle the sale. He promises to sell the painting for a minimum of £120,000, and to charge a commission of £10,000.

**Charlie** is a professional art restorer. **Bill** hands the painting to **Charlie** for cleaning. But **Charlie** makes a mistake, and damages the painting, reducing the value. It subsequently sells for £90,000.

**Bill** deducts £20,000 from the sale price, double the agreed commission, and sends **Adam** the balance of £70,000.

**Adam** is outraged. He had been expecting a payment of £110,000 but has ended up £40,000 down.

**Adam** consults **Dave** the lawyer. **Dave** advises that he might have to spend £50-60,000 to recover the loss, might not win, might not recover costs, etc.

So **Adam** considers a claim in the small claims court. The UK small claims limit is £10,000, but **Adam** has a plan. He will make three separate claims, asking for maximum damages in each.
First, he will sue **Charlie** for damaging the painting.
Second, he will sue **Bill** for damaging the painting. (vicarious liability)
Third, he will sue **Bill** for overcharging on the fees.

Is **Adam**'s plan legally permissible? Basically, is it allowed to

1. sue two different people  for the same negligence, and
2. sue one person twice for two different things.

Can a big claim be split up into smaller claims like this?

Note - for clarity,  I'm not interested in **Adam**'s dispute. I don't need to know about overcharging and the law of contracts, or liability for damage in tort law. Just the point about splitting up the case. And the case I described is just an example. Make the answer as general as possible, not restricted to this particular case.

And, as a final reminder, the jurisdiction is England and Wales.

Not asking for legal advice, you are not my lawyer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### You can only sue once on the same facts on the same defendant

The issue here is [res judicata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Res_judicata) - once a case between 2 parties has been resolved, that matter can never be litigated again. So Adam cannot split his litigation against Bill.

### Adam has suffered no damage from Charlie

If Adam now had an artwork of reduced value as a result of Charlie’s negligence he would. But he doesn’t have a damaged art work so Charlie has caused Adam no harm.

Comment: Thank you for your useful reply. Could you please make it even more useful by adding some extra information on the following questions. Q1)  Could Adam argue that his two claims against Bill rely on different facts?  In one case, he's suing on the fact that he was overcharged, in another he's suing on the fact of damage to the painting. Would that be allowed?   (Comment too long, split in two parts)

Comment: Q2) 2) Maybe Charlie isn't liable in this particular case, but I'm asking about general principles, not specifics. Imagine any scenario where two people each contribute to negligence that costs Adam £30,000. Can Adam sue them separately?  On the same facts, or slightly different facts in the two cases. And because of the small claims limit, the maximum combined compensation would be less than the injury.